# Salesforce Flow - How to use In Operator with Data Table element selected Rows

Tags: datatable, screen-flow, operators, salesforce-flow

I am using Flow element [Data Table](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_screencmp_data_table.htm&type=5)

I have scenario like, two picklist values are added on the screen e.g. Status and Type of Object, and also the comment field.

When the user clicks on next I will have to update the selected row's fields with selected Status, Type, and Comment.

[image]

**I just wanted to know that, is there any option or variable available in Data Table, usign that I can directly do a filter with '*In*' Operator in the Update Record element.**

[image]

Currently, I am able to find the solution is that, loop through the selected rows and collect the Id of selected rows, and then usign the update record element update the records. Or else I can go with an apex-defined variable or Apex Action.